# CSS transition for multiple elements on the page

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-transitions

On my page I have 2 divs:

```
<div class="mycards fight">
      <div class="card"><span class="name"></span><div id="att1"><span></span></div><div id="def1"><span></span></div></div>
</div>

    <div class="mycards fight2">
               <div class="card"><span class="name"></span><div id="att2"><span></span></div><div id="def2"><span></span></div></div>
            </div>
```

I am injecting dome text via jquery like:

`$('#att1').html(sometext); $('#att2').html(sometext);` etc.

In CSS I set the transition for these elements:

```
#att1, #att2, #def1, #def2 {
    transition: all 1s ease; 
}
```

The problem is, the transition is working only for second DIV, where #att2 and #def2 are present and it ignores it in my first DIV.

I also tried to do it via jquery :

```
$("#att1").addClass('trans');$("#def1").addClass('trans');
$("#att2").addClass('trans');$("#def2").addClass('trans');
```

in my script when it is needed, and then in CSS I defined just

```
   .trans {
        transition: all 1s ease; 
    }
```

but again, it works now only for the first DIV.

For some reason it can't do the same effect for both elemets. Not sure where is the problem.

Example where the transition is expected:

```
function bonus(val,val1,val2) {
            $.ajax
            ({url: 'bonus.php',
                data: {"var1": val,"var2": val1,"var3": val2},
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(datax) { 
                  if (val2===1) {
                            if (val===1) {$("#att1").addClass('size-50');}
                            if (val===2) {$("#def1").addClass('size-50');}
                            if (val===3) {$("#att1").addClass('size-50');$("#def1").addClass('size-50');}

                            window.setTimeout(function(){

                                if (val===1) {$("#att1").removeClass('size-50'); $("#att1").addClass('size-30');}
                                if (val===2) { $("#def1").removeClass('size-50'); $("#def1").addClass('size-30');}
                                if (val===3) {$("#att1").removeClass('size-50'); $("#att1").addClass('size-30');
                                    $("#def1").removeClass('size-50'); $("#def1").addClass('size-30');}
                                                                   },500);
                        }
                        else {
                            if (val===1) {$("#att2").addClass('size-50')}
                            if (val===2) {$("#def2").addClass('size-50');}
                            if (val===3) {$("#att2").addClass('size-50');$("#def2").addClass('size-50');}
 
                            window.setTimeout(function(){

                                if (val===1) {$("#att2").removeClass('size-50'); $("#att2").addClass('size-30');}
                                if (val===2) { $("#def2").removeClass('size-50'); $("#def2").addClass('size-30');}
                                if (val===3) {$("#att2").removeClass('size-50'); $("#att2").addClass('size-30');
                                    $("#def2").removeClass('size-50'); $("#def2").addClass('size-30');}

                            },500);

                        }

                        window.setTimeout(function(){runAll();},1000);
                
            }});
}
```

Comment: Can you post a working example please? [mcve]

Comment: What properties are you changing? I can’t see anything that would transition.

Comment: @Sfili_81 it is a complex game, I pasted a small example, when via ajax I am updating the values of att1 etc. and as it is changed via html, it should have the transition effect. It has, but only for one div.

Comment: @A.Hawort I mentioned in in my question: simply I am just changing the value inside <span>:  $('#att1').html(sometext); $('#att2').html(sometext); and the text size is changing (I added that part of code now)

Comment: I think you can create a little snippet to reproduce the error,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, I think the issue was in the conditions I had there using e.g. `val===1` which wrongly compared the values. when I replaced it for `==` now it works for both cases.

Sometimes the core issue is caused by something else...